# Installing python packages in offline embedded linux

Tags: python, embedded-linux

I was working on a pre-build Linux version running on a custom board (offline).
it already has python installed, As I was trying to install flask and its dependencies, I found every dependency of flask is dependent on a number of other packages, and finally i found my Linux version doesn't even have python-distutils installed and i cant even find a setup for it. is there a better way to install packages offline.
Nb: I've got a online pc connected to the Linux board via ssh.